# why apple hardware test doesn't see my network?

Tags: network, wifi, kernel-panic, macos

I would like to check if the new installed ram can have generated a kernel panic with **AHT** (Apple Hardware Test). Restarting by pressing the **D key** the dropdown appears for the selection of the network but mine is not present. If I try to find it by entering the network name and the WEP password I get an error.

If I see all the other networks why I do not see mine?

And why the form don't accept my data?

My system is a Mac Mini late 2012 with Mac Os Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that temporarily removing the WEP encryption allows access to the tool via the Internet and solved this issue.

Comment: I really wouldn’t be using WEP in this day & age. Switch to WPA2.